# Один js-файл на весь сайт приводит к ошибкам

Tags: javascript, frontend

У меня на сайте везде подключается один и тот же js-файл:
`<script defer src="/js/engine.js"></script>`

На главной странице у меня есть элементы с `id="img-0"` и `id="img-0"`, но на остальных страницах сайта их нет, поэтому в консоле браузера я получаю ошибки: *Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null* и *Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null*.

Участок проблемного кода:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.querySelector('#img-0').className = 'show';
};

document.getElementById('img-2').onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('img-1').classList.toggle('hide');
        document.getElementById('img-2').classList.toggle('hide');
};
```

Как в таких случаях принято поступать?

Answer (score 1):

Обычно сначала проверяют существование элемента.

```
var img = document.querySelector('#img-0');
if(img != null){
    img.className = 'show';
}
```

Comment: Можно еще короче: if(img = document.querySelector('#img-0')){img.className = 'show';}

Comment: А если функций не самое маленькое количество, то может какой-то более красивый способ есть? Например, ```data-title``` у ```body``` и обёртка кода в ```if (document.body.getAttribute('data-title') === 'index') { }```

Comment: Можно сделать универсальную функцию, например:
`function toggleClass(el,className){
    el.classList.toggle(className);
}`